# Playing with node.js: can I create a CLI app that simply displays the date and time?

Tags: javascript, node.js, command-line-interface

I'd like to see if it's possible to make an CLI app that simply displays the date and time with node.js. So far I've only figured out how to send the date and time over HTTP. Here's what I have:

```
var sys = require('sys');
var http = require('http');

var s = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  var now = require('datetime');
  now = new Date();
  res.writeHead(200, { 'content-type': 'text/plain' });
  setInterval(function() {
    res.write(now.toString());
    res.write("\n");
    now = new Date();
  }, 1000);
});

s.listen(8888);
```

There are a few problems with this. Nothing is being printed to the command line and the in the browser the datetime isn't refreshed, it is printed under the previous printout. How can I get this to print out on the command line, and how can I get this to clear the previously printed text?

I am using node.js 0.5.5.

Answer (score 1):

Use `console.log` to output things to the console.

Use [Now.js](http://nowjs.com/) to update the client.

Use `console.log('\033[2J');` to clear the logged output.

Also check out https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/modules#wiki-debugging for nice console extensions, they make things easier.

Comment: `sys` is deprecated. please don't recommend it.

Comment: Is there a alternative to `sys.print('\033[2J');`?

Comment: @Raynos, got that snippet from here: https://github.com/SchizoDuckie/Node-CLI/blob/master/node-cli.js#L121 if you know a better way of doing it, then please share :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can print to the command line in Node.js with `console.log()`. So do:

```
console.log(new Date());
```

Right now your Node.js server only responds to each request. It doesn't have a way to push new info out to the client without the client making a request. An easy way to get that to work is with some client-side javascript.

```
$(function() {
    // Update every 5 seconds
    setInterval(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url:"http://localhost:8888", 
            success: function(data) { $("#time").text(data); }
        });
    }, 5000);
});
```

This assumes you have an HTML element with an ID of time somewhere on the page.

If you just want to print stuff out to the console, you can replace your entire script with a call to `setInterval` like this:

```
setInterval(function() { console.log(new Date()); }, 5000);
```

Comment: His question mentioned how to make the browser update. This answers that part of it. It is easier than something like WebSockets.

Comment: i am refraining from a -1 here :) OP really wanted to know how to do it using node.js. :)

Comment: Yes, and if you look at his question, it says: "There are a few problems with this. [...]in the browser the datetime isn't refreshed, it is printed under the previous printout." The AJAX stuff answers that part of the question that he specifically asked. I didn't want to get into websockets, so this is a workaround for that.

Comment: have you had a look at node.js before? its something very different and so exciting :)

Comment: Can the console printout be cleared before an updated datetime is printed? I'd really like to see if I can stream basic time information over a local network without the need of a web browser at all. May sound crazy, just wondering if it's possible with node.js.

Comment: In this example, Node.js is being used as a SERVER. His question mentioned behavior on the CLIENT SIDE. The job of the Node.js server is to respond to client requests. Hence, if he wants the client to update more often, he would need to change his client. AJAX is an easy way to do it that doesn't require him to modify his server. WebSockets would also do it, but would require more modification to the client as well as the server. Yes, I have used Node.js before.

Comment: @BasicObject: Sorry, I don't know how to clear the console before each  printout. It doesn't sound like that is a requirement for streaming stuff over the network though. You could just send out UDP packets if you just want to stream stuff, and anyone who is interested can find them. Does that make sense?

Comment: So with UDP I could stream the datetime to clients over my home network using node.js? Would this require the clients to use something like telnet? What I really want is for the clients to only have to make one connection request and then have the datetime continuously update. Basically a networked clock built with javascript.

Comment: UDP is a stateless protocol. A good analogy is a message board that anyone can post to. So if your server posts to the message board, clients would just need to watch the message board for new messages, and do whatever when they got them. TCP is like a phone call, where you are having a one-on-one conversation with someone. For broadcasting the time, the "just send it out, and whoever cares will be listening" approach of UDP makes sense to me. You would then have to configure the clients to listen on the UDP socket. What do you want the clients to do?

Comment: I just want the clients to view the information that is streamed to them. The clients aren't going to be sending any information back. I plan on sending more than just date time to the clients. I'm just using a simple date time example to get an understanding of how this should work.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3192/discussion-between-jergason-and-basicobject)